# Interval of time and Conditions for doing push ups and strength training?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, strength-training, push-ups, grip-strength

Is it necessary that our body be warmed up before doing push ups? (Condition)
Is it OK to do strength exercise (mainly push ups) every 2-3 hours? (Definitely not just after and before eating, but do it whenever I get the chance)

Scenarios:

1. Suppose I'm studying in my room and after 2 hours, I need to give myself some rest from studying, so I switch to stretching, push ups, plank, dumbbells, sit ups, hand gripper. Is it OK to do so?
2. Is it OK to use a hand gripper during a boring class?

I'm not a native English speaker, so please excuse my English and my inability to formulate the question properly.

Comment: Your English is fine :) There's nothing wrong with doing some exercising in between studying sessions - I used to do it when I was gaming. It just depends how heavy you're going at with this. If its just light dumbbells, moderate amount of situps, etc; then you wont need much rest. If you are doing a high weight / high intensity, then it might be better making a session out of it and doing it once a day / every other day. Your muscles need to rest, ultimately. Lower the intensity, the lower the rest time. Use that as guidance for rest time and you should be fine.

Comment: As for warming up, you should always at least stretch out your muscles before doing any intensity motions. Stops unnecessary pain / allows you to work for longer / harder. You could do a cold session, which is basically a session you perform where you aren't warmed up, popular in swimming - but its merely to test how good you are in a not ideal scenario. So personally, from what you're doing, id stretch out for about 5 minutes and then start doing the mini work out.

Comment: One thing about the hand-gripper, your teacher might object if it makes noise, or if it slips out of your hand during class, so you might run it by him beforehand, maybe saying that it helps you concentrate.

Answer (score 1):

### Stretching

Stretching advice is backwards @Goralight

> The basic science literature supports the epidemiologic evidence that stretching before exercise does not reduce the risk of injury.

- Do static stretching **after** exercising

---

### Abs

- As this works your innercore these are fine to do daily
- Ditch basic sit-ups *(Spinal Loads ~2000N of Force)*

---

### Push-ups

Your chest needs time to recover.  Try the following:

> **On Odd Days**

- Do 200 pushups in as few sets as possible in addition to your
  regularly scheduled workout of cardio exercises.
- You can still do upper body workouts on these days if you are already
  on a program.
- This is a supplemental 200 pushups using maximum repetition sets (4 x
  50, 8 x 25 ... it's your choice how you get to 200).

> **On Even Days**

- Do 200 pushups throughout the day.
- This can be little sets of ten done every half hour or fifty pushups
  done four times throughout the day.

> **Rule**

- If your maximum is under 50 pushups, do 200 a day. If your maximum is
  above 75, do 300 pushups a day.
- Repeat the ODD/EVEN routine for a **total of 10 days**.
- Then **take three days off** and do NO upper body pushing exercises
  that work the chest, triceps, and shoulders.
- I would not recommend this workout more than once every six months,
  since it rather challenging on the same muscle groups repeatedly.

---

### Other Exercises

You can find a ton of new exercises here: http://www.coreperformance.com/knowledge/workouts/

---

***Sources:***

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10593217
- http://www.military.com/military-fitness/workouts/try-pushup-push-workout